# Implementation Issue: Deep ConvNet for Pattern Recognition

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to implement a pattern recognition model using a fully convolutional network (fig 1 in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320318304370, I was able to get the full text without signing in or anything but if it's a problem I can attach a picture too!) but I'm getting a size error when moving from the final Conv2D layer to the first fc_layer.

Here is my error message:

```
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [4 x 1024], m2: [4 x 1024] at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:283
```

Originally, as in the figure, my first linear layer was:

```
nn.Linear(4*4*512, 1024)
```

but after getting the size mismatch, I changed it to:

```
nn.Linear(4,1024)
```

Now, I have a strange error message as written above.

For reference (if it helps), here is my code:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.utils.model_zoo as model_zoo

class convnet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes=1000):
        super(convnet, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=1),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),# stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2), #stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), #nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        )

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(4, 1024),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            #nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
            nn.Linear(1024, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(1024, num_classes),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x,1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

I suspect it's an issue with the padding and stride.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from a matrix multiplication, where `m1` should be an *m x n* matrix and `m2` an *n x p* matrix and the result would be an *m x p* matrix. In your case it's *4 x 1024* and *4 x 1024*, but that doesn't work since `1024 != 4`.

That means your input to the first linear layer has size *[4, 1024]* (4 being the batch size), therefore the input features of the first linear layer should be 1024.

```py
self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1024, 1024),
    nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    #nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
    nn.Linear(1024, 1024),
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    nn.Linear(1024, num_classes),
)
```

If you are uncertain how many features your input has, you can print out its size just before the layer:

```py
x = self.features(x)
x = torch.flatten(x,1)
print(x.size()) # => torch.Size([4, 1024])
x = self.classifier(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I realise my mistake now (: just a small question ( unrelated to the original problem), in the paper the network also includes pad1x2 and so on, do you know what this means in the context of fully connected layers?

Comment: They are convolutions with `padding=(1, 2)`, no idea why they called them FC, probably because they are part of the classification head,  but at least their depiction is consistent with the other convolutions. They mention it in section 3.2.2.